# Monitor google search in Java

Tags: java, search, web, proxy, monitor

for my master thesis I need to keep track of google searches that the users perform. It should be a web project. At first I want to setup a server (that acts like a proxy) to monitor all actions (search queries) performed by the user.
The server should deliver the google search page. I need to keep track of the input the users make and the corresponding results returned from google as well.

My questen is now.. How should I start?

1. I am not really sure which webserver to use. Should I use tomcat / jetty / or something else?
   What about Java Server Faces or Servlets? I worked with JSF long time ago but I am not sure whether its a good decision to use it.
2. The server should deliver the google search page. Here is my idea: The user connects to my server. The server "reads" the google page and returns it (the source code) to the user. I think of using a listener on the default search field to monitor the search queries of the users. But how is it possible to monitor the results returned from google? The google site itself uses JavaScript I guess. So when the user makes some input it is directly sent to google and the results are directly shown on the webpage thus my webserver does not see anything from the connection between the client and the google services.

The main idea is to monitor a search query and the corresponding search results.

I just need some help and ideas to get started. This is just a small part of my thesis. I do not want to start from zero during my editing time thus I want to make sure that I make the right choices before I start.

Thank you in advance... best regards.

Comment: What is your master thesis' goal - is it just about a proxy server?

Comment: The goal is to implement a gamification approach to increase the search expertise of the users...You can think of it like a game. A possible scenario: The user could be asked to search a speficied webpage with less query parameters as possible. He makes a query and then I need to log the results returned from google. If the desired webpage is under the top 10 results he receives a badge..exp.. and so on. Users can earn points / badges / leaderships and yeah basically thats it. Hence I need to monitor the search queries and the corresponding results to analyze them...

Answer (score 0):

You could use netty as a proxy and just filter and log all search queries. But then again why even use java? From what you describe you wan't to play man-in-the-middle and manipulate/log http traffic.

A quick google search came up with this for python: https://code.google.com/p/proxpy/

Edit: and similar in java https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy

Comment: I am not experienced with Python...I know how to setup a server in java that interacts with the requested webpage (javascript) and so on...never tried it with python. But yes you are right I want to play mitm for logging the http traffic between the client and the google services.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ill throw a look at it. Do you think it is so easy the monitor the traffic? Because the search requests are sent with javascript "in the background" hence my server is not able to see them. Would it be better NOT to load the complete google page but instead to use the google search API (https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/) ? I could create a a simple page with a text field and a button. The search query is sent to my server and it uses the google search API to deliver the results... it would not look very nice but with this approach I could control input/output..